# Querying from azure db using linq takes a lot of time

Tags: performance, linq, azure

I am using Azure db and my table has over 120000 records.
Applied with paging of 10 records a page I am fetching data into IQueryable, but fetching 10 records only taking around 2 minutes. This query has no join and just 2 filters. While using Azure search I can get all the records within 3 seconds.
Please suggest me who to minimise my Linq search as azure search is costly.

Comment: What azure db are you referring to? Cosmos DB (if so, which api), sql server, something else? And what kind of performance settings did you apply (lke DTU or reserved RU's?)

Comment: Could you also show the LINQ query?

Comment: I am using Sql server and query is :
unitofwork.Repository<EntityName().GetQueriable().ToList().Skip(1).
Take(10); this is taking more that 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the query in the comment to your question, it looks like you are reading the entire db table to the memory of your app. The data is potentially transferred from one side of the data centre to another, thus causing the performance issue.

```
unitofwork.Repository<EntityName().GetQueriable().ToList().Skip(1).Take(10);
```

Without seeing the rest of the code, I'm just guessing your LINQ query should be something like this:

```
unitofwork.Repository<EntityName().GetQueriable().Skip(1).Take(10).ToList();
```

Skip and Take should be executed on the db Server, while .ToList() is at the end will materialize the entities.

Comment: sorry I wrote wrong query my query is same as your, but if i am running on a local db it is faster while trying to access db from azure it is taking time

Comment: Well, you need to find out what t-sql is actually executed on sql azure and how much data is transferred from SQL to your app. Bear in mind, that whatever performs fine when SQL instance and app are colocated on the same machine will work differently when those are located at the different sides of the data centre